# Custom UIViewController transition animation works on presentation but not on dismissal

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have `UINavigationController A`, which is the 'left side' view controller of a `UISplitViewController` and I am presenting `UINavigationController B` modally on `UINavigationController A`. This modal presentation is performed with a storyboard segue with the following properties set in Interface Builder: `Kind` = `Present Modally`, `Presentation` = `Over Current Context`, `Transition` = `Default`, `Animates` = `true`

In the root view controller of `UINavigationController A`, I have the following property:

`let themesTransitionDelegate = ThemesTransitionDelegate()`

And the following implementation of the prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    segue.destination.transitioningDelegate = themesTransitionDelegate
    segue.destination.view.frame = view.bounds
}
```

The implementation of `ThemesTransitionDelegate` is as follows:

```
class ThemesTransitionDelegate: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

        return ThemesTransitionAnimator()
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

        // THIS IS NEVER CALLED!
        return ThemesTransitionAnimatorDismiss()
    }

}
```

My custom animation works fine when presenting the modal but `animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController)` is never called and my custom dismissal animation is not used -- the standard modal dismissal animation is used instead.

I am using `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` called from `UINavigationController B`'s root view controller to trigger the dismissal of the presented modal. I have confirmed that `UINavigationController B`'s `transitioningDelegate` is not nil when the dismissal is triggered.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the wrong `modalPresentationStyle` in your storyboard. Use `UIModalPresentationCustom`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {        
    segue.destination.modalPresentationStyle = .custom //Custom presentation
    segue.destination.transitioningDelegate = themesTransitionDelegate
    segue.destination.view.frame = view.bounds
}
```

Comment: Bingo. Thanks!  Any idea why the presentation worked but the dismissal did not in this case? My instinct would be to expect both, or neither, of them to work